# $ 7(a+b) * 2 $, why would it be equal to $ 14(a+b) $ instead of $ 14(2a+2b) $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am in grade 10 and I still got this confused. I do not get why $ 7(a+b) * 2$ equals to $14(a+b)$ , I have tried working mathematically by making up questions similar to this but I still don't understand why.

We have $$ \frac{n}{2} * (2a \ + (n-1)d ) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$, I wanted to get rid of the 2 from the LHS, so I multiplied the LHS and RHS by 2.

This is the problem, I think of multiplying everything from the LHS by 2 that means, I will get $$ n* 2 (2a+ (n-1) d)  $$ which is clearly wrong .

Could someone please explain why this is wrong?
Any form of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is 2(ab) = (2*a)*b or (2*a)*(2*b)

Comment: Is $2(3*4)$ $2*3*4$ or $(2*3)*(2*4)$?

Comment: Why would you multiply each of the components on one side by 2? You have to multiply both sides by 2 the same number of times.  If you multiply 7 by 2 and (a+b) times 2 then you are multiplying the LHS by 2 two times, but if you multiply the RHS by 2 only once you aren't multiplying both sides by the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication is associative:  $(a\times b)\times c = a\times (b\times c)$.  As such, we often don't even bother writing parentheses and the expression $a\times b\times c$ is not ambiguous.

Multiplication is commutative: $a\times b = b\times a$.

These together imply that when evaluating a product of several terms, we may choose to simplify individual products in whatever order we want.

In your example $(\color{red}{7}\color{blue}{(a+b)})\times \color{green}{2}$, you have effectively $(\color{red}{x}\times (\color{blue}{y}))\times \color{green}{z}$ by letting $x=7,~ (a+b)=y,~ 2=z$.

Now, through repeated applications of commutativity and associativity (*which many people don't even bother writing the inbetween steps since it comes naturally to most people*) and removing unnecessary parentheses this is

$(\color{red}x\times \color{blue}y)\times \color{green}z = \color{red}x\times (\color{blue}y\times \color{green}z) = \color{red}x\times (\color{green}z\times \color{blue}y) = (\color{red}x\times \color{green}z)\times \color{blue}y$

Replacing back with your original numbers, that is $(\color{red}{7}\color{blue}{(a+b)})\times \color{green}{2} = (\color{red}7 \times \color{green}2)\times \color{blue}{(a+b)}=14\times \color{blue}{(a+b)}$

---

Also important to remember, multiplication is distributive over addition: $a\times (b+c) = (a\times b) + (a\times c)$

It is worth noting that if we were to go a step further with $14\times (a+b) = 14a + 14b$ and this is the same result that you would have gotten if you evaluated the products in the other order: $(7(a+b))\times 2 = (7a+7b)\times 2 = 14a + 14b$

---

The property that you thought might be correct but is not: $a\times (b\times c) = (a\times b)\times (a\times c)$

An counter-example showing this is wrong:  $2 = 2\times 1 = 2\times (1\times 1) \neq (2\times 1)\times (2\times 1)=(2)\times (2)=4$

You might be thinking of "When I have an equation, I can multiply both sides by 2 and the resulting equation will have the same solutionset" and thinking this means "multiply each item on each side individually by two" when it really is "multiply each side wrapped within parentheses by two."  That is to say, if $f(x) = g(x)$ then $2\times (f(x)) = 2\times (g(x))$, regardless how complicated of expressions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ happen to have.

$1 = 1\times 1$ becomes after multiplying both sides by two: $2\times (1) = 2\times (1\times 1)$

Answer (score 2):

Here it is in pictures. The following image represents $7(a + b)$:

[image: 7(a + b)]

In this example, $a = 2$ and $b = 3$. The rectangle is $7$ dots high, and $2 + 3$ dots wide. If we multiply this by $2$, we get two of these rectangles:

[image: 7(a + b) + 7(a + b)]

If we stack them on top of each other, we get:

[image: 14(a + b)]

which is a rectangle that is $14$ dots high, and still $2 + 3$ wide. This represents $14(a + b)$. Visually, we can see that $7(a + b) \times 2 = 14(a + b)$.

Of course, it's equally valid to splice them side-by-side too. In fact, if we separate the red and green bits, and recombine them all so that the red and green bits are next to each other, we get a picture like this:

[image: 7(2a+2b)]

This rectangle is $7$ high, and $2 \times 2 + 2 \times 3$ wide. This represents $7(2a + 2b)$. Note that we're still working with the same number of dots, illustrating:
$$7(a + b) \times 2 = 14(a + b) = 7(2a + 2b).$$
The quantity $14(2a + 2b)$ is $2$ times too big!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have four trays, each one 7 inches by a+b inches, and one inch high.  Their area is each $7(a+b) in^2$, and their volume $7(a+b)1 in^3$.
They can be set out next to each other, to form a rectangle 14 inches by 2a+2b inches, by 1 inch high.  Their total volume is $14(2a+2b)1 in^3$.
Or you can stack them on top of each other, to get a volume $(7(a+b))4 in^3$.